# Hermite - Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, hermite-polynomials

This is my first question here. I hope I can find an answer to my question. I tried to find the answer in Books, Videos, Scripts and german forums (I'm german). But nobody could help me.

It's about the Hermite - Interpolation.I try to understand a section in my script:

---

We have given:

$x_{i}, \quad i = 0, \ldots,m$ (different in pairs)
$y_{i}^{(k)}, \quad i = 0, \ldots, m\quad k = 0, \ldots, \mu_{i}\quad (\mu_{i} \ge 0)$

We want to find:

A polynomial $p \in P_{n}, \quad n = m + \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{m} \mu_{i}:\quad p^{(k)}(x_{i}) = y_{i}^{(k)}$

For reasons of continuity, the Hermitian interpolation polynomial of a function has the form

$p(x) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{m} \sum\limits_{ r = 1}^{\mu_{i} + 1} f[\underbrace{x_{0}, \ldots, x_{0}}_{(\mu_{0} + 1)- times}, \ldots, \underbrace{x_{i - 1}, \ldots, x_{i - 1}}_{(\mu_{i - 1} + 1)- times}, \underbrace{x_{i}, \ldots, x_{i}}_{r - times}] \times \prod\limits_{j = 0}^{i - 1} (x - x_{j})^{\mu_{j} + 1} (x - x_{i})^{r - 1}$.

The divided differences $f[\ldots]$  are based on a recursion scheme analogous to the Lagrangian interpolation, whereby whenever higher-order differences cannot be formed according to the definition formula, the higher-order base values must be used, e.g.

$y[x_{i}, x_{i}] = y_{i}^{(1)}$, $y[x_{i}, x_{i}, x_{i + 1}] = \frac{y[x_{i}, x_{i + 1}] - y_{i}^{(1)}}{x_{i + 1} - x_{i}}$

$y[x_{i}, x_{i},x_{i}] = \frac{1}{2} y_{i}^{(2)}$, $y[x_{i}, x_{i}, x_{i}, x_{i + 1}] = \frac{y[x_{i}, x_{i}, x_{i + 1}] - \frac{1}{2} y_{i}^{(2)}}{x_{i +1} - x_{i}}$

---

My question now is where the hermite polynomial comes from. I have not found anything on the Internet about this.

I would be happy if someone could help me!

(Sorry for my english, i'll try to improve)

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, the Hermite Polynomials are stated to come from a particular generating function:

$$
g\left(x,t\right)=e^{-t^{2}+2tx}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H_{n}\left(x\right)\frac{t^{n}}{n!}
$$
where $H_{n}\left(x\right)$ is the Hermite polynomial.

This was extracted from George Arfken's Mathematical Methods for Physicists - Chap 13.1  Special Functions.  Hermite Functions:

https://archive.org/stream/MathematicalMethodsForPhysicistsGeorgeArfken/Mathematical%20methods%20for%20physicists-george%20arfken#page/n731/mode/2up

There are additional details there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer!  It looks like there is the "hermite polynomial" and the "hermite interpolation polynomial". I'm looking for the "hermite interpolation polynomial", so $p(x) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{m} \sum\limits_{ r = 1}^{\mu_{i} + 1} f[\underbrace{x_{0}, \ldots, x_{0}}_{(\mu_{0} + 1)- mal}, \ldots, \underbrace{x_{i - 1}, \ldots, x_{i - 1}}_{(\mu_{i - 1} + 1)- mal}, \underbrace{x_{i}, \ldots, x_{i}}_{r - mal}] \times \prod\limits_{j = 0}^{i - 1} (x - x_{j})^{\mu_{j} + 1} (x - x_{i})^{r - 1}$. Do you know, where this interpolation polynomial comes from ?